# Framed list of authors in acmart manuscript

Tags: mdframed, framed

I want to use `frame`, `framed`, `mdframed`, `tcolorbox` or any other package to create a box around content.
But the content I want to put the box around comes from the .cls file.

For example, I want to put a box around the author but the author, when I instantiate it in LaTeX, isn't shown directly by the .tex file. It goes through the .cls file where it has its own way of dealing with the author.

I know I have to edit the .cls file somehow to be able to put the frames, but I have no clue how.
The document class for this attempt is

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen,review]{acmart}
```

One can find the exact template I'm using at Overleaf:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acm-conference-proceedings-master-template/pnrfvrrdbfwt

MWE:

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen,review]{acmart}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\title{The Name of the Title is Hope}
\begin{framed}
\author{Ben Trovato}
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin} 
\end{framed}
```

This doensn't work, the frame goes to another place in the beggining of the page.
When trying to edit the .cls file, I found a `\def\@mkauthor` which I believe is where the authors are being instantiated, but I even when I add `\begin{framed}` or alike to the inside of this `\def`, the results go to the initial part of the page and not where the authors are cited.

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! can you show us what you have tried so far with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your issue?

Comment: All my attempts were simple, I tried adding usepackage{framed} (or others) and then added begin{framed} (then the content from the .cls here) end{framed}. None have worked since what I am triying is basically trial and error without really knowing how .cls works. I tried putting these begin/end frameds around gdefs and box defitnitions on .cls.

Comment: Putting together a MWE may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Besides the absence of  a MWE, you can try to redefine `\maketitle`

Comment: I added some information to the problem, but I still believe I have no much to add since most of my problem comes from my own ignorance (so adding context is harder).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! Inside `\def@mkauthor` this was the last part of the def:

```
\global\setbox\mktitle@bx=\vbox{\noindent\box\mktitle@bx\par\medskip
   \noindent\addresses\@typeset@author@line
   \par\medskip}%
```

Then I could add framed to it like this:

```
\global\setbox\mktitle@bx=\vbox{\noindent\box\mktitle@bx\par\medskip
   \noindent\begin{framed}\addresses\@typeset@author@line\end{framed}
   \par\medskip}%
```

And there it was! The box around the authors!

[image: authors with box around]